# Spring Boot 2 Hibernate Search

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm trying to migrate my app to Spring Boot 2, which uses Hibernate Search.
I'm getting error while starting my app :

- With **5.5.x.Final** : `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: session`
- With **5.6.x.Final** or **5.8.x.Final** : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search`
- With **5.7.x.Final** or **5.9.x.Final** : `An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene53' does not exist`
- With **5.10.x.Final** : `NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry`

For information, currently Spring Boot `2.0.3.RELEASE` version use Hibernate core dependency in `5.2.4.Final`

Any idea, which version to use ?

**Update after Guillaume answer & a deep clean of workspace and indexes**

Using 5.9 version, exception has evolved to `No transactional EntityManager available`

**Final word**

Last error was fixed by adding `@Transactional` on the method, but it was working in Spring Boot 1 without. Weird...

Comment: So.. which version did you end up using? I am having the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826012/spring-boot-2-and-hibernate-search-which-version-do-i-have-to-use?noredirect=1&lq=1) but no matter what I try - it's either not working or not compiling ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version you should use depends on the version of ORM used. Check your dependency.

See this compatibility matrix: http://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix

If you're using the default dependencies of Spring Boot 2.0.3, the version of ORM should be 5.2.17.Final and thus you should use Search 5.9.

You also need to use Lucene 5.5.x so you probably have to upgrade Lucene if you're coming from an old Lucene version.

Comment: Thanks for the link !

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same and I have the following result(working) in this repository

https://github.com/jcangh/boot-hibernate-search

- Spring boot version 2.0.9
- Hibernate search orm 5.7.3.Final

I tried with higher versions but didn't work